# Traversing List in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list traversal, however my code is not working and I don't udnerstand why I've reassigned my pointer but it doesn't stick?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void inserter(Node *n1, int num){
    if(n1==NULL){
    Node *temp =(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data=num;
    temp->next=NULL;
    n1=temp;
    }
    else{
        Node *trav=n1;
        while(trav!=NULL){
            trav=trav->next;
        }
    }


}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    Node *l1 = NULL;
    inserter(l1,l2,5);
    inserter(l1,l2,11);
    //It goes back into the NULL bracket despite me assigning it a node?

}
```

Here is the accompanying struct

```
typedef anode {
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
}Node;
```

Thank you for any help!I'm still new to all of this.

Comment: The problem begins with the assignment `n1=temp`. You can't assign to a local argument variable, as it's just like any other local variable (except it start out initialized with a value). I suggest you either return `n1`, or research *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: In your else case you are not allocating the new node once you find the right location

Comment: The pointer `n1` is passed by value to your function, so you can't pass a new value back that way. You also declared your `inserter` function with 2 arguments, but you're trying to pass three, and `l2` is used but not defined in `main`. So the code you show should have compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `inserter()` a pointer and an `int`. If you modify that `int`, no modifications would be visible from the calling function (I think you know that already). Same goes for the pointer: `Node *` is just a numeric type that holds an address, which has been passed *by value*.

If you want to modify where `n1` points to, you'd need to *dereference* it. But because you don't want to change the contents of the memory that `n1` points to, but change the *value* of `n1` itself, your function would need to be passed a `Node **`.

Here's a quick example:

```
void inserter(Node **n, int num) {
    if (*n == NULL) {
        *n = malloc(...);
        ....;
    }
    ....
}
```

That way you would change the actual value of `n` globally instead of just locally.